# Shall I build a destructor in this classes?

Tags: class, c++11, vector

I am currently working on building an ABM model using C++.

I have classes that have the need to interact with each other, because e.g. class B needs to examine values in class A and return some evaluation on it, which then class C might want to read. Classes need not to change other classes values, only to read from them.

Class B in my current implementation has a po
inter to a vector containing all members of Class A. The pointer is there for two order of reason: it makes easier to initialize the vector, and the vector is left in the scope of main so that I can access and loop over it, calling the members of class A for each agent.

My MCVE:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class A;    // Forward declaration

class B{

    int id,
    some_value;

    vector<A> * A_vec;

public:

// Overloaded constructor
    B(int ID, vector<A> & PTR)
    {   
    A_vec = & PTR;
    id = ID;
    some_value = 0;
    };

// Copy Constructor
    B( const B& that ):
    id(that.id),
    some_value(that.some_value)
    {
    // Pointer ??
    };

// Non-default destructor -> uncomment leads to seg_fault
    /*
    ~B(){   delete [] A_vec;};
    */
// Assignment operator

    B& operator=(const B& that)
    {
        id = that.id;
        some_value = that.some_value;
    // Pointer ??
        return *this;
    };

//Methods to update different variables go here ..
    void do_stuff();

};

class A{

    B & class2_ref;
    vector<double> o;


public:

    int stuff;

// Overloaded constructor

    A(int STUFF, B & REF, vector<double> O):

    class2_ref(REF),
    o(O)

    {
        stuff = STUFF;  
    };

// Methods to update different variables go here ..
};  

void B::do_stuff()
{
    int L = A_vec->size();  
    for(int l = 0; l<L; l++)  some_value += (*A_vec)[l].stuff; // Perform some operation

};


int main(){

    int I = 5;          // Number of objects of A

    vector<double> O(12,2); // Some numbers in here

    B b(0,A_vec);

    for(int i = 0; i< I; i++)
    {
        A a(i,b,O);
        A_vec.push_back(a);
    }

    b.do_stuff();

    cout<< "Debugging MCVE" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

My question then is:

Should I implement the destructor/copy constructor/assignment operator in class B? What about class A ? If so, can you please point me to the correct syntax(for the destructor the one above in comments leads to seg fault).

My understanding is that this might be one of the case in which I am happy with a "shallow" destruction of the pointer, because both `class B` and `vector<A>` will go out of scope at the return statement. `class B` owns the pointer, which gets destructed when it is due, and the same for vector.

But then, what about the other member from the rule of three?

There is only one object of class B planned, but I might (small chance) want to generalize later on.

Comment: Please format your code, first.

Comment: Also, there's no need to `delete` a pointer that you never `new`'d up, which may explain the segfault

Comment: @SoheilHassasYeganeh I formatted it, hope that's better now.

Comment: @Alejandro I figured that is the reason for the segfault. I am wondering though, since I keep reading that raw pointers data member need to be taken care in the destructor. So, given the way a initialize it in the constructor, it's safe as it is? What about copying?

Comment: you must deallocate what you allocate. it is the best that the one who allocated in the first place will be the one to deallocate. this is  (one of the ) meaning of RAII (resource aquisition is initialization)

Comment: @DavidHaim So what about this case? In this example, deallocation is done by the default destructor at the return statement. Is this ok/safe? What other issue can arise from having the pointer inside?

Comment: a_vec is not dynamiclly allocated so there is no need to deallocate it.

Comment: Can you elaborate and turn this in to an answer?

Answer (score 0):

if a class have a pointer type, you should implement a destructor, and i would suggest implementing a copy and an assignment operator as well, else you will be dealing with the same object from 2 different places, which could cause you some errors, for example -

```
void someFunction(B &b)
{
  B a = b;
}

B b(0,A_vec);
someFunction(b); //After finishing someFunction, it will try to delete the vector from a , but it is the same vector you used in b.
b.do_stuff(); // Would cause a seg error
```

And for the destructor syntax, just delete the vector, not its content, it will use the vector default destrctor on the content:

```
delete A_vec
```

just make sure you dont use it if its not initialized, i would suggest just building a empty vector on each ctor of the class, that way you wont get a seg fault and you can use delete.

Comment: Using `delete A_vec` in the dtor with the class at it stands lead to double free error. Also, I wish to keep the pointer inside the class to point a vector outside of it. I don't want to have another vector inside with a copy of what's outside, neither I want to have only one vector but inside the class.

Comment: I was assuming you want to generalize, as you said, thus having more then 1 B, keep in mind the different between delete[] and delete, using delete A_vec will erase the vector content, using delete[] A_vec will try to use  A dtor on each member of A_vec, while not using any thing will simply erase the pointer, leaving the vector in the heap.

Comment: I see, but I still would like to have multiple vectors outside of the class.

Comment: As a general rule, if you have a * type in the class, you will need a dtor, else you will have a memory leak (if you do not handle it some where else), also i would suggest not having a reference as a member, also edited the prev comment, damn enter caused it to be sent early :)

Comment: In general, yes. What about here?

My current understanding is that what I have above is safe. I have a vector in main.

I have a pointer inside the class. The pointer is just a variable holding a memory address.

At the return statement class is destroyed, and default dtor takes care of the pointer, but doesn't touch the vector. Then vector is destroyed, again calling its default destructor.

Comment: It is not safe, you should either change it to "vector<A> A_vec;" , or add a dtor with "delete A_vec;" , when you are holding a vector<T>* member and leaving the scope it will simply delete the pointer, while leaving the vector itself and the content on the heap, it will not use the default dtor.